# Finding Sphenic Numbers - Not Producing Expected Output

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool PrimeNum (int n) {
    if (n<=1) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}

bool findSphenic(int num, int count) {
    if (num == 1 && count == 3) {
        return true;
    } 
    if (count > 3 || num == 1) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int j = num - 1; j > 1; j--) {
        if (num % j == 0 && PrimeNum(j)) {
            if (findSphenic(num / j, count + 1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


void display (int n) {
    for (int k = 1; k<=n; k++) {
        if (findSphenic(k, 0)) {
            printf("%d\n", k);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int num;
    printf("Type in a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    display(num);
    return 0;
}
```

I want it to print out any number in the range from 1 to n that is sphenic num but after fixing bool Primenum and bool findSphenic several times, it still doesn't give me the answer I want. It just prints out "Type in a number" and after I give a number nothing happens.

Example:

Type in a number: 45

Nothing happens. It supposes to print 30 since it's a sphenic num.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] and show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Anyway, you need to debug the `findSphenic` function.  It never gets to the line line `return true;`.

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. Use pen and paper to keep track of variables for recursive calls.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a Sphenic Number is the product of three distinct primes, e.g. 2*3*5 = 30, 2*3*7 = 42. 40 is not a Sphenic Numbers since it is a multiple of 2^2 = 4. Are you expecting the program to print out all Sphenic Numbers up to the number entered?

Comment: I suggest you re-visit the logic of your findSphenic() function as it doesn't appear to check that the prime factors it finds are distinct. Also, I'd look again at the efficiency of the approach you've taken. It should be quite easy to make it much more efficient.

Comment: You may well get away with it while you're dealing with small numbers, but mixing floating point arithmetic into an integer-only calculation is not a good idea.  You have `for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {` — you would do better with `for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {` which avoids integer overflows and using floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @UpAndAdam OP's code is c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of your function which works. As you can see, the loop counts up instead of down.

```
bool findSphenic(int num, int count) {
    if (num == 1 && count == 3) {
        return true;
    } 
    if (count > 3 || num == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
        if (num % j == 0 && PrimeNum(j)) {
            if ((num/j) % j == 0) return false;
            if (findSphenic(num / j, count + 1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Notice that it also checks that there can not be repeated factors. I don't think you can easily do that counting down. On my old laptop (Core i5), it finds (without printing) the 19919 Sphenic numbers below 100,000 in 10.7 seconds. Though the following is still quite naive, it takes 0.18 seconds to do the same, illustrating that efficient code does not always have to be complicated.

```
void myfindSphenic(int num) {
  // Print all Sphenic integers up to num
  int i, j, k, count, numfound;
  numfound = 0;
  for (i=30; i<=num; i++) {
    count = 0;
    k = i;
    for (j=2; k > 1 && count<=2; j++) {
      if (k % j == 0) {
        k /= j;
        if (k % j == 0) break;
        count++;
      }
      if ((count == 0) && (j>num/(j*j))) break;
      if ((count == 1) && (j>(k/j))) break;
    }
    if ((count == 3) && (k == 1)) {
      //printf("%i  ", i);
      numfound++;
    }
  }
  printf("Found %i Sphenic numbers not greater than %i\n", numfound, num);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a completely different approach:

A sphenic number can be written as a product of three prime numbers, `p_1 * p_2 * p_3`.
This automatically means that at least one of those prime numbers should be smaller than the cubic root of your number. So you let a counter from 1 up to the cubic root and if you don't encounter a prime number, being a divisor of your number, you can stop.
If do you find a prime number, being a divisor, you can divide your number by that and do the whole thing again, but this time you continue up to the square root of the remaining number. e.g. for 1001:
You let your counter go from 1 up to 11, but you'll need to stop at 7 because that's a prime number, being a divisor.
Next: 1001/7 = 143, so now you need to go up to the square number of 143 (which is almost 12), and indeed, you'll encounter 11, being a prime number, which is a divisor, and 13 is just the leftover, being a prime number as well.